# PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$SourceID = $this->source_information->SourceID;

// the following fails 

if($results = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT .... R.Name = '$release_name' AND S.SourceID = $this->source_information->SourceID  AND S.ReleaseID = R.ReleaseID"))

// this will works  
if($results = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT .... R.Name = '$release_name' AND S.SourceID =  $SourceID  AND S.ReleaseID = R.ReleaseID"))
```

I have a ton of code with $this->source_information->SourceID sort if thing in it and I really don't what to rewrite it, tell me I can make this work some how.

edits follow:

exit(var_dump($this->source_information->SourceID));

returns(string(2) "18")

**Thank you for bringing up prepared statements. I will use prepared statements from now on.**

Comment: Please post the result of `exit(var_dump($this->source_information->SourceID));`

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: exit(var_dump($this->source_information->SourceID)); returns string(2) "18"

Comment: ever thought of using prepared statements?

Comment: if you were using prepared statements instead of interpolating variables directly into query, there would be no such error at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Simple variable interpolation* syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple), i.e. `"$this->foo"`, will only resolve a maximum of one nested object. `"$this->foo->bar"` is interpreted as `$this->foo` plus the string `"->bar"`. Which is why it's complaining about the `source_information` object. If you want to embed deeper nested objects, use the [*complex variable interpolation* syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
"... S.SourceID = {$this->source_information->SourceID}  AND ..."
```